# A simple puzzle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

You could try taking a snooze with this
It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss
It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin
But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin
Even though it makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it
Until one collapses and dies from its hit
There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs
And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab
It's not immaterial, it's slow when it's falling
It flies through the air, the rattle of death following
An object so common you don't care about it
Without it, though, you wouldn't have the energy to keep rhyming

Comment: what does "throw a jab" mean ?

Comment: A [jab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jab) is a type of punch.

Comment: This riddle requires some serious rewording. Most of the lines describe what the object is *not* (hard to pinpoint it then) and some of the lines seem irrelevant that you can't hope to use them to find the object. Instead, it's more like using them to confirm they fit the guess once you have made one, yet the links are so tenuous. I'm referring to the *snooze*, *dies from its hit* and *energy to keep rhyming* lines. Instead, describe what the object is known for, e.g., what it's used for, it can be see-through, etc. The only useful lines here are that it falls slowly and makes noise.

Comment: Futhermore, some hints put us in a train of thought that is deceiving for reaching the solution and they make the whole process unproductive. When you mention the word snooze, I'm going to look for things related to sleep (in practical terms), not what you had in mind. This is just like hinting you can use a car to eat your food and your intended explanation is that if you dump the food on it, you can eat it off it. There are more lines that suffer from this.

Comment: Fixed everything, I guess

Comment: Minor edits to improve a question are fine, but you've completely rewritten this one and now all of the answers are referring to things that aren't in the question anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my try, not sure if it's right:

> Guilt

You could try taking a snooze with this

> When people feel guilty they might try to "sleep it away".

It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> You won't feel better after it, since you haven't resolved whatever it is that's making you feel guilty.

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> Everyone has things they feel guilty about. Not 100% sure about the skin part, maybe an allusion to 'blood on your hands'?

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> You wouldn't want to make your family or friends feel guilty.

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> I think the noise refers to 'noise in your head', the nagging feeling you get when you feel guilty. However, people try and ignore it and act like it's not there, hence "no one pays attention to it".

Until one collapses and dies from its hit

> I took this line as a metaphor for the point when the guilt overcomes a person, and they can no longer ignore it ("Dying of guilt")

There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> Guilt isn't something physical, so you it wouldn't leave any physical mark.

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> This again could refer to idea that fighting guilt isn't going to work, and that you need resolve the underlying issue itself instead.

Comment: question updated, please update your answer

Answer (score 4):

This might be far off... really far off... but is the answer:

> Fecal Matter

You could try taking a snooze with this

> I mean, you could take a snooze with just about anything

It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> Unless youre into that kind of stuff.

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> It's everywhere. On your phone, on the toilet seat, on your keyboard... pretty much everywhere!

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> You'll probably get smacked.

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> People let flatulence get by, because:
>
>  *Whoever spoke last set off the blast.*
>  *Whoever smelt it dealt it.*
>  *Whoever denied it supplied it.*
>
>  No one wants to take the blame.

Until one collapses and dies from its hit

> Until it really smells and people faint (dying figuratively here). Darn you SBDs! (Silent, but deadly)

There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> Scents wouldn't leave any physical marks you can see

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> No one's a winner here.

Comment: Sadly, you're pretty far off. But I like the way you think! ;)

Comment: Can you update your answer for the updated question?

Answer (score 4):

I *might* have it...or I might be really far off

> A clock/watch?

You could try taking a snooze with this

> You usually sleep with an alarm clock by your bed.

It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> Because, you know, it wakes you up...

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> Wristwatches are on your skin. Clocks are on your phone, you know, they are pretty common.

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> This is where a clock doesn't really make sense...but I guess you don't generally shove clocks in your children's face?

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> Tick...tock...yeah, that's all background noise.

Until one collapses and dies from its hit

> I think this is misleading. The author wants you to think the "one" is a human, but in reality, it's that same alarm clock. It "dies" because you hit the snooze button.

There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> Same logic as above. You don't puncture/scar/scab a clock.

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> Okay, this too can be explained by hitting the alarm clock, or the fact that a wristwatch does nothing to protect your fist.

Comment: Like your train of thought, but that isn't the answer I was hoping for :)

Comment: "There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs" could also be the marks that watches leave on your skin, since there are no wounds.

Comment: The question was updated, your answer isn't applicable anymore. Maybe you can update it?

Answer (score 2):

Could be

> Fear

You could try taking a snooze with this
It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> Its hard to get sleep when you are in a state of fear

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> People are controlled by fear so its everywhere, also fear can give you goosebumps which appear on skin.

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> You would not admit the fact that you are afraid to your family, cause it may make you look weak.

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it
Until one collapses and dies from its hit
There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> People tend to go about their lives even during a state of panic elsewhere,but when it hits them ,they are emotionally down, and only then do they notice.

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> When you are fighting scared you are destined to lose

Comment: I was going to answer this first.

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> wind ?

You could try taking a snooze with this

> in outdoors

It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> as it's basically cold

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> this applies

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> it's annoying on their faces

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> because they're accustomed to it

Until one collapses and dies from its hit

> when it's really strong

There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> it never inflicts such force

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a  jab

> as it slows you down

Sorry about the spoiler tags. Was the first post.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! You need two line breaks to make a new paragraph, and to spoiler something out you put it on its own line and add `>!` before it. Great answer, though!

Comment: I changed the question to make it less broad. Maybe you can update your answer to reflect on the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Is it...

> a nail?

You could try taking a snooze with this
It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> Beds of nails are a common torture device. They're used in magic tricks where the magician lays down on them without being harmed (since they are not particularly fun to sleep on).

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> fingernails

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> Generally people do not like to threaten their family with *any* pointy objects.

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> Construction workers poounding in nails are often very loud, but still routine if you live in the city.

Until one collapses and dies from its hit

> If part of a building falls down, people notice.

There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> Nails do not scar since they have no flesh.

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> A glove made of nails would hurt, and your fingernails won't help since they're by your palm.

Admittedly, the last two are questionable...

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Heart

You could try taking a snooze with this
It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> I'm not sure yet.

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> Heart symbols are common, especially for tattoo designs.

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> This seems off, because if they're shorter than you and you hug them, you just brought your heart near their face.

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> Your heart beats all the time, making noise, but your brain tunes it out.

Until one collapses and dies from its hit

> Heart attack

There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> Heart attacks have no visible wounds.

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> You shouldn't let your heart lead you to violence; it won't protect you.

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't what you're looking for, but might it be

> Dirt

You could try taking a snooze with this
It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> It's not fun going to sleep dirty, or taking a dirt nap, i.e. being dead.

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin
But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> There's dirt everywhere, people sometimes have it on their skin, but you wouldn't throw it in your family's faces.

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> Earthquakes make a lot of noise, but usually we ignore dirt.

Until one collapses and dies from its hit
There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> If you don't clean up, you can get sick any die, with no visible external injuries

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> It won't stay on your hand; it will all just fall off.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Water

You could try taking a snooze with this

> Sleeping in a waterbed or one of those [float pods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_tank)

It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> Early tanks were uncomfortable and required some type of system for the user to breathe with

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> Earth is mostly water, and it's not uncommon for it to touch you

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> People are very careful to avoid getting water in the eyes when giving baths to babies

Even it though makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> Waterfalls can be pretty noisy, but people usually don't pay attention to the sound

Until one collapses and dies from its hit

> Water is not something people think is deadly until they hear of people dying from floods or something

There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> Drowning leaves no wounds, scars, or scabs

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> You can try to punch water, but it's not going to do much for you

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

> Stress/Tension

You could try taking a snooze with this
It won't be pleasant, won't bring you any bliss

> you can't sleep easy with stress

It's practically everywhere, maybe even on your skin

> Tension in our skin, skin gets stretched.

But you wouldn't bring it near the faces of your kin

> We hide our Stress/Tension from our family.

Even though it makes lots of noise, no one pays attention to it

> Stress makes lot of noise inside our head, but no one can hear it.

Until one collapses and dies from its hit

> And there is a time when person who goes through it, can't bear it anymore, his body gives up. Heart attack or high blood pressure takes the persons life.

There are no puncture wounds, no scars, no scabs

> the wounds which are caused by stress do not show any physical signs of damage.

And it won't be a good glove when you throw a jab

> Stress does not work in the favour of the fighter.

Comment: Even though it's not what I'm looking for, it's a great try!

Comment: Don't tell me, it is a synonym.

Comment: It isn't, so you're safe

Comment: @RahulParashar Oh, it's definitely "cinnamon," I know it!   Oh, wait...